# Does with_entities result in smaller objects?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I only need column values and don't need anything else provided by a model, I use `with_entities` and then iterate over the tuple-like `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` objects which result.

Am I correct that these objects are smaller than the full-blown model objects I would otherwise be getting?

example:

```
models = Thing.query.filter_by(user_id=3).all()
type(models[0])
# => project.models.Thing
#
# vs
#
tuples = Thing.query.with_entities(Thing.id).filter_by(user_id=3).all()
type(tuples[0])
# => sqlalchemy.util._collections.result
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct.